# How to use regex to match two / characters but not three in URL?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have urls www.test.com/test1/test2/test3. We are using regex on Google tag manager and Google analytics to perform different types of operations on levels test1 and test2 seperately. What kind of regex "fires" Google only on www.test.com/test1/ but not on www.test.com/test1/test2. Content between / characters change so the solutions should probably rely on the number of / characters.

Answer (score 0):

First, go to **Variables** and make sure that the following is enabled (checked):

`Enabled Built-In Variables` **>** `Pages` **>** `Page Path`

Next, go to **Triggers**, and create a new **Trigger**

**Trigger Name:** "Path Is Only One Dir Level"

**1) Choose Event** - Select `Page View`.

**2) Configure Trigger** - Select `Page View`.

**3) Fire On** -

- Select `Some Page Views`
- Select `Page Path` **>** `matches RegEx` **>** `^\/([^\/]+)\/?$`

Next, **Save Trigger**.

Then, in your **Tag**, within **Fire On**, choose `More`, then select trigger you just made.

**Note:** The above is an example of setting up the trigger to eval on page view, but you can setup the event type to whatever. The main part is this is the **Fire On** part of the **Trigger** configuration.

This trigger is a regex match against the path portion of the URL (`location.pathname`). It matches the following:

- Starting at the beginning of the value,
- Match a forward slash,
- Followed by one or more of anything that is not a forward slash,
- Followed by an optional forward slash,
- Followed by end of string (value).

So, it will match

```
/test1
/test1/
```

but it will not match

```
/test1/test2
/test1/test2/test3
etc..
```